# How to trace HTTP requests in Spring Boot 3 with Micrometer & Zipkin

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin, micrometer-tracing

My purpose is to trace every request to my system. I watched 2 video below on Youtube to config Micrometer & Zipkin for tracing.

- [Implementing Distributed Tracing in Microservices with Spring Boot 3.0, Micrometer, and Zipkin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgirTJiBkV4)
- [Java - Spring Boot 3: Tracing de Microservices con Micrometer y Zipkin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbQHsNEUs_k)

But, when I access `http://localhost:9411/zipkin/`, it worked abnormally and make me confused.

[image]

So I have some questions about it:

1. At first, I never perform any requests, why there are so many request on Zipkin dashboard?
2. I use Postman to perform three requests (1 from `order-service`, 2 from `product-service`), why it only show the requests from `order-service` like this
   [image]
3. Why the spans (Zipkin dashboard) always is 1. Although every requests must go through `api-gateway service` first, it is not the same as video 1.

For Micrometer config, I reference [Micrometer and Zipkin: How to Trace HTTP Requests in Spring Boot 3](https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/micrometer-and-zipkin-in-spring-boot/#:%7E:text=By%20default%2C%20Micrometer%20only%20traces,set%20the%20probability%20to%201.0.)

I insert `management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0` to each `application.properties` file and these dependencies below to each pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-observation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.zipkin.reporter2</groupId>
            <artifactId>zipkin-reporter-brave</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

This is my architecture system:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I try to check `management.tracing.sampling.probability=1.0`, and it raise a error:

```
Cannot resolve configuration property 'management.tracing.sampling.probability'
```

I really don't understand why it like that, after that I found the different, there are 2 denpendencie, they look pretty similar:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        ...................
        ...................
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I try to reach out the spring docs: [`actuator.micrometer-tracing.tracer-implementations`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.micrometer-tracing.tracer-implementations) and I realize the dependency I actually need is `spring-boot-starter-actuator`

I insert three new dependencies from docs:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentelemetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

To summary, we will use these dependencies for tracing http request with Micrometer & Zipkin.

- spring-boot-starter-actuator
- micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel
- opentelemetry-exporter-zipkin

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, adding this helped in my case: `management.zipkin.tracing.enabled=true`

Answer (score 0):

> Why the spans (Zipkin dashboard) always is 1. Although every requests must go through api-gateway service first, it is not the same as video 1.

This for me was because I was creating a RestTemplate instance myself, which meant Micrometer could not automatically instrument it causing no context to be propagated. Adding the following configuration and autowiring the bean instead of creating a RestTemplate myself fixed it.

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        return restTemplateBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

This blog post describes the issue in detail: https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/spring-boot-why-you-should-always-use-the-resttemplatebuilder-to-create-a-resttemplate-instance-d5a44ebad9e9